# Example for non-existent limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I build an expression using the basic functions (power functions, ln, exp
but NOT trig functions), such as (for example)
$f(x)=4+ln(e^x/(x+2)-5x^3)-10^{3x}.$
Suppose that f(x) is well-defined for high x values.

a) Is it possible that f(x) has no limit as x goes to infinity:
no real limit and no $+\infty$ or $-\infty$?

b) Is it possible that f(x) is bounded as x goes to infinity,
but it has no limit as x goes to infinity?

David

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the function you built (take care that, in the real domain, it is undefined for the range $0.51 \leq x \leq 11.56$ in which the argument of the logarithm is negative)
$$f(x)=4+\log \left(\frac{e^x}{x+2}-5 x^3\right)-10^{3 x}$$ when $x$ is large and negative $$f(x)\approx 4+\log(-5x^3)=4+\log(5)+3\log(|x|)$$ and it goes to $+\infty$.

On the other side, when $x$ is large and positive, $$f(x)\approx -10^{3 x}$$and it goes very fast to $-\infty$.

Comment: But the OP is concerned only with "high $x$ values" and limits as $x\to \infty.$

Comment: @zhw. I had the feeling that this was what I tried to answer. So, I probably don't see your point. Cheers.

Comment: Probably because there is no point to what I said. I thought something else was going on. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @zhw.No problem at all, be sure ! Cheers

Comment: Did you see the "for example" part? You missed a couple of billion other functions.